# Does unwind segue pop off view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As an unwind segue in Objective-C moved backwards through view controllers does it pop off the view controllers as it goes or does it leave them there?

Comment: What do you mean by "pop off?"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Did you try running an unwind segue? What did your experiments show? Would it even make sense for an unwind segue to leave view controllers on the navigation stack?..

Comment: No, I haven't tried running one yet. I'm very new to obj-c and am reading apples tutorial on developing for iOS. I would assume it does because it doesn't make much sense to leave view controllers on the navigation stack. Just looking to see if that is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is removed from stack when they are dismissed. Unwind segue is kind of dismissing the view controller. In case you toggle from one view controller to second and from second to third. Those view controllers remain on stack but when you reverse them they are removed from stack.